# What does an AP mid do to help achieve map visibility and maintain it?

Tags: league-of-legends

So what is my role in getting the map visible and keeping it as an AP mid? Would I buy wards or would I let others buy them and put them up? what is my responsibility when it comes to map awareness?

Answer (score 4):

It is EVERY player's responsibility to buy wards. Of course, supports buy the majority of wards, and an AD carry might only buy a couple over the course of an entire game. Playing as mid, I buy a ward every time I go back, or two if I can afford it. Place a ward either on the ramp toward the enemy jungler's wraiths, or in the small brush on the opposite side (drake side if you are on the blue team, Baron side if you are on the purple team). Coordinate with your support, as well. If your support wards dragon, then place your ward in the top river (wraith ramp if you are on the blue team, in a brush if you are on the purple team). After laning phase, you should still carry a ward or two whenever you can, up until you are finishing your final build and have no more slots for them.

Answer (score 3):

The AP mid does not need to put wards on top of their priorities. However a couple wards here and there will help the game dramatically if you have the gold.

- You can ward **the bushes around your lane** to prevent ganks.
- You can ward **the dragon or baron** if someone else hasn't done that already.
- And finally, you can ward **the wraiths in the enemy jungle.** This ward is key to keeping track of the enemy jungler, aiding in your team's efforts to counter jungle, and also allowing you to possibly take the wraiths for your own farm (depending on your champion and how the game is going). As a jungler myself I find myself warding here very often and I can not stress how helpful it can be.

These three spots should be the most important to ward as an AP mid. Note that you may not need to ward all of them, sometimes you will not have the money, you may not fear ganks from the enemy jungler, or someone else might have it warded.

Answer (score 3):

*The mid has the responsibility for his own survivability.*

---

> **But I need gold for gear!**

**Solutions:**

- Make a deal with your Jungler, so he can ward one side of the river
  or even both.
- Buy one ward to ward at least top river. (Bottom usually are warded
  at dragon, it helps a little)
- Play in defense mode. Stay near your turret, and behind minions.
  going forward just for a quick harassment.
- Keep your scape route up, while pushing your lane. (Flash, Ghost, etc)

*One or two wards every 5~10min will not hurt your gold pool that much. just focus on last hitting minions. every ~3 minions you can buy one ward.*

Answer (score 3):

Honestly it depends on your champ as play style and how aware of the map you are. If you like to invade the enemy jungle or keep tabs on him get some aggressive wards so you can hank him at his red. If you play a hamp like Leblanc or kennen you don't have to ward for survivablities sake. If you play a Champ like brand or Malzahar thoug getting ganked by a cc will wreck you. You have to play to your style, your champ, enemy champ, your jungler and the enemy jungler. Honestly if you are playing lol you should be hyper aware of all variables to achieve a win.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is a great image of where to ward. 
[image]

As a mid Cassiopeia or Karthus, I will ward a little south of this image, in the lower bush at the corner on both sides of the map. This will help give vision of the river and the crossroads. This also helps see if top or bot are moving mid. And also help determine when to steal the buffs from the enemy team's jungle.

I also agree that it is every team member's responsibility to purchase wards or items that cast vision. Teemo and Shaco can use their ablities to give vision on these areas as well.

It becomes even more important if you have a poor bot or top lane comp that is getting beat up pretty bad and will lose the tower soon.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: just to clarify, why do you think it'll become more important when the other lanes are doing poorly? could you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend keeping top side of your bush warded try to get your jungle to do it but if he refuses to you can do it yourself if u have a extra ward in your inventory its never a bad idea to ward dragon too and that is in basic all that you should be doing in terms of warding and map sight control

Answer (score 0):

Just ward bushes to your left and right. You need wards to prevent ganks from enemy jungler. Trust me he will try to gank you as soon as you leave the safe ground. By safe ground I mean if you over push you will be an easy target. If you have wards you will know when and from where is he coming so you can safely retreat and continue with farming.

Occasionally you can ward Dragon, but you should leave other warding spots to your teammates. You should just focus on revealing sides of the mid lane.

Comment: Care to explain why this is useful?

Comment: Well ofc I will. You need wards to prevent ganks from enemy jungler. Trust me he will try to gank you as soon as you leave the safe ground. By safe ground I mean if you over push you will be an easy target. If you have wards you will know when and from where is he coming so you can safely retreat and continue with farming...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would put a ward at the enemy wraiths; this gives you vision of the enemy jungler entering the river possibly your jungle. Your jungler would normally ward the other exit of the enemy jungle near the enemy blue.

If the enemy appears at either of those locations, you should take care. However, if they don't appear, tell your top and bottom lanes to be careful and give your jungler a heads up as the enemy jungler could be trying to steal a buff.

If you have all the entrances to the river covered, it is very hard for an enemy jungler to gank and invade. Plus, it makes for great opportunities to counter gank and gank an invading jungler.